# How do i can add const % on click in transform:translate with jquery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to make easy slider, but i dont know if there is option to make a const "%" on click with transform:translate with jQuery.

There is my code:

```
$(".arrowLeft").on("click", function () {
    $('div.slider div p').css('transform', 'translate(-50%, -50%)')
})
```

and for example i want to add on every click "200%" to translateX.
Is there any solution for this?

Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increment a variable to do it.

Tell me if it solve your problem.

```js
let tNum = 0;

$(".arrowLeft").on("click", function () {
  // change "20" by 200 in your project
  tNum = tNum + 20;
  console.log(tNum);
  $("div.slider div p").css('transform', 'translate(-' + tNum + '%, -' + tNum + '%)');
})
```

```css
.arrowLeft { position:absolute; left:250px;top:10px }
div.slider div p { width:200px; height:200px; background:grey }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrowLeft">Click</div>

<div class="slider"><div><p>P</p></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer.
It works but only for one side.
I want to make reviews slider, which 5/6 reviews whios we can skip with arrow from left to right.
There is my code:

```
let tNum1 = -50;
let tNum2 = -150;
let tNum3 = -350;
let tNum4 = -550;
let tNum5 = -750;
let tNum6 = -950;

$('.arrowLeft').on('click', function () {
    tNum1 = tNum1 + 200;
    tNum2 = tNum2 + 200;
    tNum3 = tNum3 + 200;
    tNum4 = tNum4 + 200;
    tNum5 = tNum5 + 200;
    tNum6 = tNum6 + 200;
    console.log(tNum1);
    console.log(tNum2);
    console.log(tNum3);



    $('div.slider div p:nth-of-type(1)').css('transform', 'translate(-' + tNum1 + '%, -50%)');
    $('div.slider div p:nth-of-type(2)').css('transform', 'translate(-' + tNum2 + '%, -50%)');
    $('div.slider div p:nth-of-type(3)').css('transform', 'translate(-' + tNum3 + '%, -50%)');
    $('div.slider div p:nth-of-type(4)').css('transform', 'translate(-' + tNum4 + '%, -50%)');
    $('div.slider div p:nth-of-type(5)').css('transform', 'translate(-' + tNum5 + '%, -50%)');
    $('div.slider div p:nth-of-type(6)').css('transform', 'translate(-' + tNum6 + '%, -50%)');

})

$('.arrowRight').on('click', function () {
    tNum1 = tNum1 - 200;
    tNum2 = tNum2 - 200;
    tNum3 = tNum3 - 200;
    tNum4 = tNum4 - 200;
    tNum5 = tNum5 - 200;
    tNum6 = tNum6 - 200;
    console.log(tNum1);
    console.log(tNum2);
    console.log(tNum3);



    $('div.slider div p:nth-of-type(1)').css('transform', 'translate(+' + tNum1 + '%, -50%)');
    $('div.slider div p:nth-of-type(2)').css('transform', 'translate(+' + tNum2 + '%, -50%)');
    $('div.slider div p:nth-of-type(3)').css('transform', 'translate(+' + tNum3 + '%, -50%)');
    $('div.slider div p:nth-of-type(4)').css('transform', 'translate(+' + tNum4 + '%, -50%)');
    $('div.slider div p:nth-of-type(5)').css('transform', 'translate(+' + tNum5 + '%, -50%)');
    $('div.slider div p:nth-of-type(6)').css('transform', 'translate(+' + tNum6 + '%, -50%)');

})
```

Like i said, right to left works, but left to right..
Reviews stop in the middle of "div" and stack on each other..

Comment: You can validate my answer if you find it usefull. Thank you